# What do you call critical analysis of all sides of some issue instead of from just one side?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

What’s a word or term for visualizing a phenomenon—some
bit of news or an event from history or daily life—from
multiple perspectives?

For example, suppose some event happened in your
country's history or your country fought some war:
the basic sentiment of most people will be to support
their own country and its military actions.

But if you wanted to make a case both in favor of and
also against that war, *without* following the general
emotional consensus in your country, what would this
be called?

Comment: Is the word "visualizing" important here? Other than that one word, the rest of the question seems very non-specific about what means are used to make the comparison.

Comment: What I meant to ask is what term we can use for analyzing a story from both ends, without being emotionally attached, presenting both sides of story

Comment: Understood. In that case, I think "viewing" is more appropriate than "visualizing". [Meaning 16](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/view?s=t) seems to be what you're trying to say.

Comment: I've changed your tag [tag:word-choice] to [tag:single-word-requests] since you haven't offered any words to choose from. Please have a look at the info link in the tooltip for the tag (hover your mouse over the tag to see it). There's a checklist in the info link that you should use when requesting a term.

Comment: "Both sides of the coin."

Comment: an independent observer.

Answer (score 2):

**balanced**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/balanced)

> 3. (Rhetoric) (of a discussion, programme, etc) presenting opposing points of view fairly and without bias

Comment: This seems a better reference: "giving equal attention to all sides or opinions SYN fair a balanced view/account  *a balanced account of what happened* "  https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/balanced

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'Impartial' would fit here and would be especially apt in the case of the war example.

[Cambridge definition of Impartial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impartial)

not supporting any of the sides involved in an argument:

e.g.: A trial must be fair and impartial.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [objectivity](https://www.google.com/search?q=objectivity&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&oq=objectivity&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0l4.2439j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> the quality of being [objective](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&ei=jFlOW4G7KISUsgXlyouQAg&q=objective&oq=objective&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0i131i67j0i67l2j0i7i30j0i67j0i7i30j0i67l3.21961.22785..23867...0.0...105.1100.11j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30j0i13i30j0i13i10i30.EM4c7JujKKg)
>
> Objective: (of a person or their judgment) not influenced by personal feelings or opinions in considering and representing facts.
> "historians try to be objective and impartial"

Answer (score -1):

**Critical Thinking**:

On multiple online platforms, one can find people who berate and lambast others with hackneyed, cliched misinformation chosen purely to confirm their own misguided bias and often fuelled by their own emotional insecurities.  Too often it is dribble bereft of critical analysis or purposeful scrutiny, but their diatribe is well practiced with the hope it makes them appear intelligent.

Critical thinking involves looking at situations rationally, analyzing available data, and drawing meaningful, fact based conclusions only after you have thoroughly investigated both sides of the discussion.

Critical thinking takes time: time to read and be informed; and time to ponder and consider before reaching a conclusion. To often people fall victim to confirmation bias, only seeking out information that aligns with their existing beliefs, and gliding past any other opinions.  In the echo chambers of social media they find like-minded individuals to reconfirm and reinforce their existing bias, and their scrutiny goes no further. It is true that our brains often prefer cognitive ease — quick judgments and mental shortcuts — over critical analysis, and in our seemingly time deprived lives simple answers can be a welcome haven. We step away from 'being told' towards 'knowing' when we practice **critical thinking**, and it is crucial if one wishes to better understand values and virtue and build a scaffold, based on independent thinking, that gives one the ability to make principled judgments.

...but that is my understanding. ...and you are free to agree or disagree.   StíofánÓ.

Comment: 'Critical thinking' is a good answer. Perhaps the downvote is because no supporting reference is given (and they're easy to find), or perhaps it's because the first paragraph, while true, comes across as a rant.